# Illegal Triangle Exception

Tags: java, exception, io

Im having some problem with my homework and was hoping you guys could help me out. The assignment is this:

> (**IllegalTriangleException**) Programming Exercise 11.1 defined the **Triangle** class with three sides. In a Triangle, the sum of any two sides is greater than the other side. The **Triangle** class must adhere to this rule. Create the **IllegalTriangleException** class, and modify the constructor of the **Triangle** class to throw an **IllegalTriangleException** object if a triangle is created with sides that violate the rule, as follows:

```
   /** Construct a triangle with the specified sides */
    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
       throws IllegalTriangleException {
        //Implement it
    }
```

Okay. Here is the triangle class.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
 private double side1 = 1.0;
 private double side2 = 1.0;
 private double side3 = 1.0;

 public Triangle() {

}

 public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
     this.side1 = side1;
     this.side2 = side2;
     this.side3 = side3;
}

 public double getSide1() {
    return side1;
}

 public double getSide2() {
    return side2;
}

 public double getSide3() {
    return side3;
}

 public void setSide1(double side1) {
    this.side1 = side1;
}

 public void setSide2(double side2) {
    this.side2 = side2;
}

 public void setSide3(double side3) {
    this.side3 = side3;
}

 public double getArea() {
     double p = getPerimeter() / 2;
     return Math.sqrt(p * ((p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3)));
}

 public double getPerimeter() {
     return side1 + side2 + side3 ;
}

 public String toString() {
     return " Triangle: Side 1 = " + side1 + " Side 2 = " + side2
             + " Side 3 = " + side3;
}

}
```

The **IllegalTriangleException** class:

```
 public class IllegalTriangleException extends Exception {
private double perimeter;

 /** Construct an exception*/
  public IllegalTriangleException(double perimeter) {
    super( "The sum of any two sides is greater than the other side" +  perimeter);
    this.perimeter = perimeter;
}
 /**return the side*/
  public double getPerimeter() {
    return perimeter;
}
}
```

Here is the **TriangleWithException** Class:

```
  public class TriangleWithException {
    //The perimeter of the triangle
    private double perimeter;
    private double side1 = 1.0;
    private double side2 = 1.0;
    private double side3 = -1.0;

    //Number of objects created
    private static int numberOfObjects = 0;

        //construct a triangle with perimeter 
    public TriangleWithException(double side1, double side2, double side3)  {

    }
    //Construct a triangle with a specified perimeter.
    public TriangleWithException(double newPerimeter) {
        setPerimeter(newPerimeter);
        numberOfObjects++;

    }
    //Return perimeter
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return perimeter;
    }

    //set new perimeter
    public void setPerimeter(double newPerimeter) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (newPerimeter >= 0)
            perimeter = newPerimeter;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Any two sides needs to be grater than the other side");

    }
    // Return numberOFObjects
    public static int getNumberOfObjects() {
        return numberOfObjects;
    }

    //return area of triangle
    public double findArea() {
        double p = getPerimeter() / 2;
        return Math.sqrt(p * ((p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3)));
    }
    }
```

And at last, the **Testprogram**.

```
public class TestTriangleWithException {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      new TestTriangleWithException(/** What goes here?*/);
      new TestTriangleWithException(/** What goes here?*/);
      new TestTriangleWithException(/** What goes here?*/);
}
    catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
}
    System.out.println("Number of objects created: " + 
            TriangleWithException.getNumberOfObjects());
}
}
  class TriangleWithException {
//Perimeter
private double perimeter;

//number of objects created
private static int numberOfObjects = 0;

//Construct a triangle with a specified perimeter
public TriangleWithException() throws IllegalTriangleException {
    double side1; 
    double side2; 
    double side3;
}

//construcj a triangle 
public TriangleWithException(double newPerimeter)
throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (newPerimeter >= 0)
        perimeter = newPerimeter;
        else
            throw new IllegalTriangleException(newPerimeter);

}

//Return numberofobjects
public static int getNumberOfObjects() {
    return numberOfObjects;

}

//Return the area of the triangle 
/** How do define getPerimeter for the type IllegalTriangleException?
 * How do i resolve side1, side2 and side3 as variables?*/
public double findArea() {
     double p = getPerimeter() / 2;
    return Math.sqrt(p * ((p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3)));
}
}
```

So, the issues I'm facing at the moment are *these*:

I need to modify the constructor of the **Triangle** class to throw an **IllegalTriangleException** if the rule is violated.

I need to figure out if `Perimeter` is the variable i need and not the sides in the exception classes.

I am a beginner so while the solutions might seem obvious to you they are not for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's an insane amount of code to post.  Please only give what is necessary.

Comment: Apart from general guidance on the structure of your Triangle class, I don't see the relevance of the Circle classes, and the shouldn't be here. You seem to have taken the Circle structure literally, but adopting the validity test for the radius won't work for Triangle.

Comment: Why does the Exception have the parameter "perimeter"? And how do you define a triangle only having the "perimeter"?

Comment: I understand, so the `Triangle` class is functioning as it should. Do you mean **all** the classes?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Oh, I've been writing it in my first language and didn't realize it. Not only `perimeter`is used in `Triangle` ?

Comment: What did you try? How did you approach the problem?

Comment: @Khilmarsen the perimeter is NOT enough to define a triangle - you need more data (length of sides, angles, or ...) - that is pure mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger But isn't perimeter and area enough to define it?

Comment: @Khilmarsen area? Maybe the late time, but I am unable to find where you are passing the area to the constructor of the triangle. And I can't find it in the assignment (neither the perimeter)?? Start simple...

Answer (score 2):

I think should help you out. I added selection statements to  constructor and and helped you with the the `Exception` class. If your `GeometricObject` class is good, this code should work for you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleWithException {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalTriangleException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // create triangle
    Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
    boolean done = false;
    double side1 = 1.0;
    double side2 = 1.0;
    double side3 = 1.0;

    System.out.println("Enter three sides: ");

    while (!done) {
        try {
            side1 = input.nextDouble();
            side2 = input.nextDouble();
            side3 = input.nextDouble();
            triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
            done = true;
        }
        catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.print("Enter three sides:  ");
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }




    System.out.println("Enter a color:  ");
    String color = input.next();
    triangle.setColor(color);

    System.out.println("Enter true or false for triangle filled: ");
    boolean filled = input.nextBoolean();
    triangle.setFilled(filled);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(triangle.toString() + 
            "\narea: " + triangle.getArea() + 
            "\nperimeter " + triangle.getPerimeter() +
            "\ncolor: " + triangle.getColor() + 
            "\nfilled: " + triangle.isFilled());
}

}
```

Original Triangle class

```
class Triangle extends GeometricObject {

protected double side1 = 1.0;
protected double side2 = 1.0;
protected double side3 = 1.0;

public Triangle() {
}

public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) throws   IllegalTriangleException {
    if (side1 >= side2 + side3)
        throw new IllegalTriangleException(side1);
    else if (side2 >= side1 + side3)
        throw new IllegalTriangleException(side2);
    else if (side3 >= side2 + side1)
        throw new IllegalTriangleException(side3);
    else {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

}

public double getSide1() {
    return side1;
}

public double getSide2() {
    return side2;
}

public double getSide3() {
    return side3;
}


public double getPerimeter() {
    return side1 + side2 + side3;
}

public double getArea() {
    double p = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
    double area = Math.sqrt(p * (p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3));
    return area;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Triangle side 1 = " + side1 + ", side 2 = " + side2 + ", side 3 = " + side3;
}
}
```

IllegaTriangleException class

```
class IllegalTriangleException extends Exception {

private double side = 1.0;

public IllegalTriangleException(double side) {
    super(side + " is larger than other two combined");

} 

public double getSide1() {
    return side;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    ...
}
```

and the Exception:

```
public class IllegalTriangleException extends Exception {

    public IllegalTriangleException() {
    }

    public IllegalTriangleException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    ...

}
```

---

now you have to add the code for checking the triangle and eventually throwing the exception (only the structure, I won't do the whole job):

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;

        if (E*R*R*O*R)
            thrown new IllegalTriangleException("Any two sides needs to be grater than the other side");
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you're only taking in the sides, which is when you should be checking for the `Exception`.
So, we have:

> side_1 < side_2 + side_3
>  side_2 < side_1 + side_3
>  side_3 <
>   side_1 + side_2

this can be rearranged to:

> side_1 < side_2 + side_3
>  side_1 > side_2 - side_3
>   side_1 >
>   side_3 - side_2

this reduces to:

> side_1 < side_2 + side_3
>   side_1 > absolute_value(side_3 -
>   side_2)

So, we have:

```
public TriangleWithException(double side1, double side2, double side3) 
                            throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (side1 >= side2 + side3 || side1 <= Math.abs(side3-side2))
        throw new IllegalTriangleException(yourMessage);

    //otherStuffInConstructor
}
```